# Too much space between cells

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, constraints

I'm having trouble with reducing the spacing between my cells, I want it to be 1 px. Inside my cell I have a stackView which fills my entire cell, both set to 70.

I can accomplish almost what I want by adding negative constrains, but then my cells gets too big, I only want it to be 70. I set the cell to 70 in the custom cell class

```
self.frame.size.height = 70
```

And my stackView is set to the very same. I don't see why I get that amount of spacing between my cells?

[image]

Comment: will you show some code?.

Comment: I'll do so, however most of it is made in storyboard

Comment: if you didn't mention these details, how we will understand. So please update your question.

Comment: Between 2 cells of table view always has no space !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below method to adjust the cell height;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 78;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Between 2 cells of table view always has no space

2) You set `self.frame.size.height = 70` in your custom cell. But it will be useless ! Try this datasource method

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

3) Please check the height of the white view